# How to interupt an operation from R in Shiny GUI?

Tags: r, shiny

There are a way that I can interrupt one R operation that is executing with an actionButton located in my Shiny App?

when I start a long time operation the app become irresponsive, so it's necessary a button to cancel the operation that is blocking the aplication.

Comment: Here's an indication that this is not possible: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/aZqOxOdvBxU. However, a pleasant surprise in the form of a positive answer would be welcome.

Comment: Thank you @BenBarnes I also think that at this point this is impossible. but let's wait maybe someone else had some workround

Comment: At this time I also think that this is impossible. I will also wait for some workround. Until there you can take a look at withProgress function http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/withProgress.html to show some progress and maybe try to go multithread as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835122/multithreading-with-r