# R - is matrix algebra inherently multithreaded?

Tags: r, multithreading, parallel-processing, blas, atlas

I am trying to understand if basic matrix algebra operations in `R`, e.g. `A %*% B`, are inherently multithreaded, such that when I run the same script on a server with 72 cores, all matrix algebra computations will take advantage of the 72 cores.

Apparently, `R` on Linux/MacOS is inherently single-threaded ([SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835122/multithreading-with-r)).

But matrix algebra in `R` uses `ATLAS`, based on `BLAS`, which apparently can take advantage of multiple cores if built as such.

**How do I check if `ATLAS` used by my `R` installation is built with mulithreading?**  I downloaded R 3.5.3 binary for MacOS from [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/).
The [R FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/RMacOSX-FAQ.html#Which-BLAS-is-used-and-how-can-it-be-changed_003f) does not mention if `Rblas` is built multithreaded or not.

**Furthermore, how do I control the number of cores used for matrix algebra in `R`**